# Change Text and href of a tag after login

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<li><a href="login.php" class="changelogin" title="Log In">Log In</a></li>
```

This link will go to the login page and there I will login but after login it should change the text to "profile" and and href= "userwork.php".

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) 
    {    
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "$('.changelogin').text('Profile')";
        echo "$('.changelogin').attr('href', 'userwork.php')";
        echo "</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you'd absolutely have to do it with jQuery, do it as follows: 

`if(isset($_SESSION['mail'])):?><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.changelogin').text('Profile').attr('href', 'userwork.php');
})</script><?php endif;`

You've missed the document.ready... and of course load jquery first!

Comment: wrap those modifiers in a `$(document).ready` other than that I don't see why your current code wouldn't work.

Comment: @Damien solution is good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not doing something like this ?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo '<li><a href="userwork.php" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>';
} else {
    echo '<li><a href="login.php" title="Log In">Log In</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: simple and clean solution.

Comment: Or in one line: `echo "<li><a href='".(isset($_SESSION['email']) ? "userwork.php' title='Profile'>Profile" : "login.php'>Log In")."</a></li>";`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<li>
<a href="<?php echo  isset($_SESSION['email']? 'userwork.php' : 'login.php'; ?>"
       class="changelogin"
       title="<?php echo  isset($_SESSION['email']?'profile':'Log In'; ?>"
       ><?php echo  isset($_SESSION['email']?'profile':'Log In'; ?></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Damien solution is simple, if you still want to achieve this by using jQuery than you use like:

```
<?php
    // your session start
    session_start();    
?>

<input type="hidden" name="is_session" id="is_session" value="<?=(isset($_SESSION['email']) ? 1 : 0)?>">
<li><a href="login.php" class="changelogin" title="Log In">Log In</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var is_session = $("#is_session").val();
        if(is_session == 1){
            $('.changelogin').text('Profile');
            $('.changelogin').attr('href', 'userwork.php');
        }
    });
</script>
```

In this example you can store session value into a hidden input field and use it after page load by using jQuery.